# I've installed drake and set up drake with Matlab, now what?

Tags: drake

I'm new to the drake, I've installed the drake from source and build the Matlab binding. However, I didn't find any step by step tutorial on the drake document. I don't know where to get started, any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the matlab use case is not officially supported anymore.  We support the python interface (and you can use python from matlab), but we do not test with matlab anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the MIT course [Underactuated Robotics](http://underactuated.mit.edu/underactuated.html) which uses Drake extensively.

You can also check the [`examples`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples) directory for examples